# Islamic way of sex

Tags: practical-islam, sex

I am a woman and me and my husband want children. I wanted to inquire is there a correct way to have sex. I have heard that one needs to do wudoo first then 2 rakaat nafil namaz to ask for allah's blessings for children.
Please guide me as its being almost 18 months since my marriage and we desperately want children.

Please guide us on the correct way to have sex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salam sister!

Actually islam is a complete way of life, then of course it gives perfectly guides us in having healthy and allowed sexual relationship. There are certain things, which you have to make sure during sex, like which actions are allowed, mubah and haram.

All of the ways to have sex are allowed, except those, which are forbidden, as proven from this verse of Quran:

> [2:224] Your wives are a tilth for you; so approach your tilth when
>   and how you like and send ahead some good for yourselves; and fear
>   Allah and know that you shall meet Him; and give good tidings to those
>   who obey

- You can do it in all positions, no issues with that, as proven from above verse of Quran
- You can do it being naked, but better cover yourself
- Rear entrance is haram
- You are right that you should pray 2 rakat nafl, but not before every sexual act, but  only at first night. It is proven from Sunnah.
- When you are about to start,then before taking off clothes, both of you should recite this (Never ever forget this dua, as whoever recite this dua, before sex,his child will never be harmed by satan):

> بِسْمِ اللهِ اللَّهُمَّ جَنِّبْنَا الشَّيْطَانَ ، وَجَنِّبِ
>   الشَّيْطَانَ مَا رَزَقْـتَنَا

Translation

> "I am having relations in the name of Allah. O Allah save us from
>   Satan and keep him away from the children You grant us".

The child that is born after the recitation of this dua will never be harmed by Satan.

- Cleanliness must be maintained, before and after
- When man has reached climax, you have to stay there for a while
- Some medical experts say that if both climax together,than the chances of fertilization are high.

In the end, try to get yourself checked up properly from medical doctor.

May Allah bless you with pious child

Comment: -1 for the incorrect translation of the hadith. Once fixed will update it.

Comment: Well the hadith you toke the dua from is this http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/81 with a translation of the dua and here with transliteration http://sunnah.com/bukhari/80/83

Comment: "When man has reached climax, you have to stay there for a while" - Can you give a reference for this condition?

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 books written by Irfan Ullah Khan that deal with the matters related to sexual life in the light of Quran and Sunnah. Here are the 2 books:

1. The Halal Sex Guide: 
   https://happymuslimfamily.org/halal-sex-guide/
2. Better Love with Better Half: 
   https://happymuslimfamily.org/better-love-with-better-half/

The book "The Halal Sex Guide" discusses how to spice up the sex life from the practical point of view, whereas "Better Love with Better Half" deals mostly with sharai matters and fiqh opinions though it also has some chapters on tips and techniques.